# Javascript - function always returns 0 (for loop not executing)

Tags: javascript

I am working on a [coding exercise](http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/bonfire-sum-all-numbers-in-a-range#?solution=function%20sumAll%28arr%29%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20outcome%20%3D%200%3B%0A%20%20for%28var%20x%20%3D%20Math.min%28arr%29%3B%20x%3CMath.max%28arr%29%3B%20x%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20outcome%20%2B%3D%20x%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20return%20outcome%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AsumAll%28[1%2C%204]%29%3B%0A) for freeCodeCamp. The purpose of the exercise is to take an array as input that contains 2 numbers. It should return the sum of those two numbers and all numbers between them.

I tried writing a simple for loop using `Math.min()`, and `Math.max()` as parameters, but somehow my funtion always returns 0. The basic logic is for the for loop to start at the lowest number in the array, then increment by 1 until it gets to the biggest number in the array, and always add the number to the output variable.

```
function sumAll(arr) {
  var outcome = 0;
  for(var x = Math.min(arr); x<Math.max(arr); x++) {
    outcome += x;
  }
  return outcome;
}

sumAll([1, 4]);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are using `Math.min` and `Math.max` wrong. See the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max.

Comment: Tip: debug by executing all the relevant expressions individually; that should have uncovered the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.min` and `Math.max` don't accept a *list* as argument. If you want to apply a list to them, use [`Math.min.apply(Math, arr)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Answer (score 1):

`Math.min` and `Math.max` does not take an array as argument, but a list of numbers as separate arguments.

To make those methods work on array, use this trick:

`Math.min.apply(Math, [1,2,3]) // --> 1`

The same goes for `Math.max`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Math.max` and `Math.min` wrong. To use them with arrays, you can use the spread operator. (Note: the spread operator is new in ECMAScript 6, so it isn't supported in older browsers.) See below:

```
function sumAll(arr) {
  var outcome = 0;
  for(var x = Math.min(...arr); x<Math.max(...arr); x++) {
    outcome += x;
  }
  return outcome;
}

sumAll([1, 4]);
```

See the MDN for more details:

- [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)
- [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)
- [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Math.min ()` and `Math.max ()` don't take arrays as a parameter. Is this an acceptable alternative?

```
function sumAll(min, max) {
  var outcome = 0;
  for(var x = min; x<max; x++) {
    outcome += x;
  }
  return outcome;
}

sumAll(1,4);
```

Some others have provided ways to get the lowest/highest numbers out of an array.

Comment: The exercise specifically says that it has to take an array as input.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `Math.min(arr)`. `Math.min(arr)` evaluated to `NaN`. If you need to get minimal number value from `arr` use `Math.min.apply(Math, arr)` instead.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 function sumAll(arr) {
  console.log(arr);
  var outcome = 0;
  for(var x = Math.min(...ar1); x<Math.max(...ar1); x++) {
    outcome += x;
  }
  return outcome;
}
```

`Math.min(...ar1)` the three dots inside the paranthesis is called spread operator

The spread operator allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for array literals) are expected.

[page link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Answer (score 0):

```
function sum(arr) {
    var min = arr[0] < arr[1] ? arr[0] : arr[1],
    max = arr[0] > arr[1] ? arr[0] : arr[1],
    result = 0;

    for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
      result += i;
    }

    return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code will never enter into the for loop because in the for loop initialisation part you are assigning `x` with the min value of array and then once agin you are comparing x with min of array`x<Math.max(arr)` so the condition fails. then the `outcome` is always 0.